# React Input Number

Tags: reactjs

Estuve viendo que en react el *Input number* no funciona como lo hace en HTML.
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?. El componente devuelve un item de una lista que estoy iterando. el input debería tomar un valor de esa lista y permitir al usuario cambiarlo. Lo que no me deja hacer es cambiar el valor del input. Ejemplo, input number devuelve numero 3, no me deja cambiar ese numero ¿Cómo podría hacer funcionar el input number?

```
return (
   
    <div>
      {listProducts.map((product) => {
        return (
          <div key={product.id} className="div-cart">
            
            <input type="number" value={product.quantity}/>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tiene el _Input number_  y por qué dices que no funciona como lo hace en HTML? Yo acabo de hacer una [prueba](https://codepen.io/jaimemenendez/pen/dyJzbOz) en codepen con el fragmento que adjuntas y parece funcionar justo como en html. Por favor, agrega esos detalles a tu pregunta y describe a que te refieres con *hacer funcionar*. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Jaime, grcs por la rta. Lo que no me deja es cambiar el numero que muestra el input. Me muestra ok el valor pero no me deja cambiarlo. investigando un poco vi que es algo particular de React, investigare mas en todo caso.

Comment: Nam, deberías haber empezado por ahí. Edita tu pregunta y describe ese problema de que no te deja cambiar el valor. Tu pregunta es **totalmente válida**, sólo que debes describirla bien, para que quien la responda esté al tanto del problema al que te refieres y sirva a futuros usuarios como referencia. Normalmente se maneja con el evento `onChange`. Gracias por editarla.

Comment: grcs, esta editada

Answer (score 0):

En react, necesitas manejar el estado de los inputs de manera manual. Para ello, guarda un estado que represente la lista de productos y en cada uno de los inputs escucha por el evento `onChange`. Cuando se dispare el evento, detectarás mediante el `id` el input del producto que fue actualizado, y actualizarás esta propiedad en el estado del componente para que sea renderizado de manera correcta por react.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Component = ({listProducts}) => {
   const [products, setProducts] = useState(listProducts) 
    
   const handleChange = (e) => {
     const newProduct = products.map(product => {
       if(product.id == e.target.id){
          product.quantity= Number.parseInt(e.target.value);
       }
       return product;
     })
     
     setProducts(newProduct)
   }
   
   return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => {
        return (
          <div key={product.id} className="div-cart">
            <input 
              type="number" 
              value={product.quantity} 
              id={product.id} 
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>)
}

const products = [
  {id: 1, quantity: 4},
  {id: 2, quantity: 4},
  {id: 3, quantity: 4},
  {id: 4, quantity: 4}
]

ReactDOM.render(<Component listProducts={products} />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En React los formularios tienen que ser [componentes controlados](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Como ejemplo básico:

```
export default function App() {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setQuantity(event.target.quantity);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Controlled Components</h1>
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="quantity"
          value={quantity}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Te sugiero usar alguna librería para manejo de formularios, esto dado a que ya vienen diseñadas para tener un buen manejo y performance de formularios.

Las más populares:

1. [Formik](https://formik.org/)
2. [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/)